# Informix ODBC Driver... Invalid connection string attribute?

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I had never used PDO for to connect with Informix database before, this error poped up while I was running a basic query:

```
SQLSTATE=01S00, SQLDriverConnect: -11005 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php

class prueba{
private static $cn = null;

 public static function conectar(){
    if(self::$cn !== null ) {
      return self::$cn;
    }
    try{
       self::$cn= new PDO("informix:host=localhost; service=30000;
    database=mrroot; server=mrserver; protocol=onsoctcp;
    EnableScrollableCursors=1", "mrtony", "");
       return self::$cn;

    } catch (PDOException $ex){
       die($ex->getMessage());
    }
  }


 public static function consulta(){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM fr_envio";

    $cn = prueba::conectar();

    $resultado = $cn->prepare($query);

    $resultado->execute();

        echo '<table>';
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['enviopre'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['enviofra'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row ['enviopec'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row ['envioval'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

        echo '</table>';

}

}


$prueba = new prueba();

$prueba->consulta();
?>
```

I've tested the same code on Mysql, just change the connection string, and everything works perfect, it seems like the connection string is missing something, and I dont know what it could be.

I followed what is says in this tutorial:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.virtapp.doc/TD_item2.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ummm... try specifing the connection string in just one line.

```
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53# cat test.php
<?php

$db = new PDO("informix:host=irk;service=3046;database=stores7;
server=irk1210;protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "informix", "ximrofni");

print "Connection Established!\n\n";

$stmt = $db->query("select * from systables");
$res = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
$rows = $res[0];
echo "Table contents: $rows.\n";


?>
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53# php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=01S00, SQLDriverConnect: -11005 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.' in /usr3/products/php5/test.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /usr3/products/php5/test.php(4): PDO->__construct('informix:host=i...', 'informix', 'ximrofni')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr3/products/php5/test.php on line 4
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53#
```

Like this:

```
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53# cat test.php
<?php

$db = new PDO("informix:host=irk;service=3046;database=stores7; server=irk1210;protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "informix", "ximrofni");

print "Connection Established!\n\n";

$stmt = $db->query("select * from systables");
$res = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
$rows = $res[0];
echo "Table contents: $rows.\n";


?>
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53# php test.php
Connection Established!

Table contents: systables.
root@irk:/usr3/products/php53#
```

Comment: I'm a fvcking retard... Thanks hahaha, by the way, a friend helped me install and configure the driver on ubutu, but he didn't told how to do it.... Do you know any tutorials to do this? apart from the ones that are on stackoverflow, because I tried to do it with a few of them and it didn't work suscefully for me

Comment: Other than installing the CSDK package and setting the env variables (PATH/INFORMIXDIR) there is not much to it.

Have a look at

 https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247884.pdf
 
It has lots of samples of how to use the different Informix APis (including ODBC) and some basic troubleshooting.